# Replace special characters to display as in database

Tags: sql-server, regex, vb.net, special-characters

I made a screen in asp.net for user to input data. There is a field Remarks varchar(200). When user inputs any special characters like &, ", > it is saved in sql server as it is but when it is displayed on screen, those characters change to &amp, &quot, &gt

I fixed &amp using replace -

```
txtRemarks.Text = IIf(row.Cells(26).Text = "&nbsp;", "", IIf(row.Cells(26).Text.Contains("&amp;"), row.Cells(26).Text.Replace("&amp;", "&"), row.Cells(26).Text))
```

But how to replace multiple characters like this?

For example,
when

```
dgtremarks = "super > & su"per
```

it appears on screen as

```
dgtremarks = &quot;super &gt; & su&quot;per
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem with the SQL server, but the display layer; unless you're using SQL Server's `FOR XML PATH` functionality? If so, we need the SQL.

Comment: No, I am not using FOR XML PATH functionality. I was able to fix & issue but there are issues with other characters

Comment: You need to lookup HTMLDecode and HTMLEncode. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8 don't try to do this with a bunch of weird character replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying on the screen you can use the following:

WebUtility.HtmlDecode(mystring)

I suggest understanding HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode